# Issue with InvariantCulture in Universal Windows Apps

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I'm trying to extract data from a webpage for my apps. I'm using the following code snippet:

```
public static string Substring(this string @this, string from = null, string until = null, StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.* InvariantCulture *)
{
    var fromLength = (from ?? string.Empty).Length;
    var startIndex = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(from) ? @this.IndexOf(from, comparison) + fromLength : 0;
    if (startIndex < fromLength)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("from:Failed to find an instance of the first anchor");
    }
    var endIndex = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(until) ? @this.IndexOf(until, startIndex, comparison) : @this.Length;
    if (endIndex < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("until:Failed to find an instance of the last anchor");
    }
    var subString = @this.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
    return subString;
}
```

But it says StringComparison does not contain a definition for **InvariantCulture** 
And compile time is as follows:

1. A value of type `?` cannot be used as a default parameter because there are     no standard conversions to type `StringComparison`
2. `StringComparison` does not contain a definition for `InvariantCulture`

Comment: Sure, it just isn't available in a Universal app.  You target .NETCore, the small version of .NET.  It didn't fit :)

Comment: How can I  resolve the issue? Give me some directions @HansPassant

Comment: You'll have to stop trying to use it, as simple as that.  It cannot be a real problem, web pages never use invariant culture.  They are created by people, they can't help having a culture.